# Post archives link yields a 404 Not Found

Tags: theme-development, themes

I'm writing my own WordPress theme and I'm having problems with the archive page. My archive link yields a *404 Not Found*. I get this link from `get_post_type_archive_link("post")` and it just adds `/archives` to the base URL of my website.

My permalink structure is set to *Post name* and I have clicked *Save changes* to make sure that any pending `.htaccess` changes were saved. Category links work fine. Here's a list of PHP files in my theme root:

- 404.php
- front-page.php
- functions.php
- index.php
- pagebottom.php
- pagetop.php
- single.php
- taxonomy.php

Any idea why the archive link isn't working?

Comment: Because you have no archive.php.

Comment: Beat me to it @vancoder :)

Comment: Checkout the template heirarchy @Pieter http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Comment: Also check out this handy [checklist](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_File_Checklist).

Comment: @vancoder I have tried copying `index.php` to `archive.php`, but it doesn't change anything. The [template hierarchy sheet](https://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png) confirms that it shouldn't matter, since WordPress will use `index.php` as a fallback anyway.

Comment: Are you sure that `get_post_type_archive_link("post")` is outputting archives? That does not sound right.

Comment: Hmm... I just tried that again and I can no longer reproduce the behavior. I'm not getting any return value from it right now... perhaps I was wrong earlier. Is this the wrong way to get the post archives link? I should mention that I'm not using the front page (`front-page.php`) as a post archive but more like a static information page. Am I missing a crucial setting?

Comment: Seen [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Archive_Index)?

Comment: Based on the advice from the article you linked to, I set up a special page and configured it to use a custom-made page template for blog archives. In this template I construct a `WP_Query` that fetches the most recent posts, which appears to work nicely. If you post your comment as an answer, I can give you credit for it.

Comment: I don't think a link to the codex constitutes a credit-worthy answer, but thanks.

Comment: A 404 is never caused by the absence of a template file, the request is determined to be a 404 long before WordPress attempts to load a template. This is how it's possible to have a 404.php template.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem: the template hierarchy is not serving up the right file from the hierarchy (at least it should serve index.php if there is no archive.php), but instead it gives a 404.

My solution is to go to the wp-admin interface, select settings>permalinks and change the common settings to some other permalink setting (I changed it from "post name" to "day and name"). Now try again and it should work. Afterwards you can change the settings back to where they were (in my case: "post name") and it will still work, no 404.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at WordPress Template Hierarchy [here..](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)
For your problem with Archive page you need to create **Archive.php** file in the theme root. If you want to create separate Archive page for different custom post type then just add post-type name prefix in archive.php file.
Example **product-archive.php**
Here is small example for archive page.

---

File name:- archive.php

```
<?php
```

/*
Template Name: Archives
*/
get_header(); ?>

```
    <?php the_post(); ?>
    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

    <?php get_search_form(); ?>

    <h2>Archives by Month:</h2>
    <ul>
        <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?>
    </ul>

    <h2>Archives by Subject:</h2>
    <ul>
         <?php wp_list_categories(); ?>
    </ul>

</div><!-- #content -->
```